# generate a sequence of 'if ... else if ... else if ... else' with a macro list with #inclusion of file

Tags: c++, macros

I have to develop a function that crack a dynamic list of messages

MsgCracker.hpp

```
void MsgCracker<TCaller>::crackMessage(const FIX44::Message& message, const FIX::SessionID& session_id)
{
     FIX::MsgType msgType;
     message.getHeader().getField( msgType );

     #define DECLARE_MSG_TYPE(MSG_NAME, MSG_TYPE)     \
       else if(msgType==MSG_TYPE)                     \
       {                                              \
             m_Caller.onMessage( (const FIX44::MSG_NAME&)message, session_id,timestamp );                \
        }

    if(false){}                                                                                                                         
    #include "MsgTypes.hpp"
    #undef DECLARE_MSG_TYPE
    else
    {
          FIX44::MessageCracker::crack(message, session_id);
    }
}
```

MsgTypes.hpp

```
DECLARE_MSG_TYPE (TradeCaptureReport  , FIX::MsgType_TradeCaptureReport);
DECLARE_MSG_TYPE (SecurityList , FIX::MsgType_SecurityList);
```

But I'm getting compile error : error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’

Comment: Are you sure there is no C++ solution to this? You ran into one of the precise reasons why macros are typically a bad solution.

Comment: You seem to confuse what's done at (before) compile time by the preprocessor and what's done at runtime appearing inside an `if()` statements conditional scope. What is the problem you actually want to solve with this?

Comment: Most compilers have options to stop after preprocessing. Do that and looked at the preprocessed code. That should hopefully give a "Doh!" moment. (That "Doh!" moment could come before as well, if you realize that macros and their use are not C++ statements and thus should not be terminated as such.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a semicolon after every line in `MsgTypes.hpp`, so your macros are expanded with a semicolon after them, like so:

```
if (false) {}
else if (...)
  { ... }; // <- !!!
else if (...)
  { ... };
```

Needless to say, that leads to the exact compiler error you see - there should be no semicolon before an `else`.

Let it be known though that you should avoid macros for this. C++ has other tools (e.g. templates, polymorphy) to solve this exact problem in a way that humans can understand directly. The difficulty in finding this simple problem is exactly one of the reasons why macros suck. If you describe what you really want to do in a new question, people will be glad to offer you options.